# 'chartit' is not a valid tag library

Tags: django

I am using chartit to plot charts in my django website application, here is what I have in my template:

```
{% load chartit %}
{{ chart|load_charts:"container" }}
```

but when I want to render the template, I get the following error:

'chartit' is not a valid tag library: Template library chartit not found, tried django.templatetags.chartit,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.chartit,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.chartit

Any help would be appreciated a lot! :)

Comment: Have you installed the library? `pip install django_chartit`

Comment: Yes, I have. In fact in views.py I can import from chartit but the error occurs in the template!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add `chartit` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.